# Do I need to import variables in all my scss files?

Tags: css, reactjs, import, sass

I have an scss colors file with some variables.

I use these variables in other files. But I'm using '@import' on every file I need.
Is there any way to import globally and not each file?

I'm using react and node-sass in my project.

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you have to import variables.scss into each "component.scss", there is no way to import it "globally"

Comment: css only works on css. For a css to get a css variable, you need to import a css file into another file. For your question, there's no react or JS involved.